# Passar ponteiro de sql.DB como parametro de método

Tags: golang

Tenho uma struct que possui um método `save` que recebe como parametro um ponteiro para o acesso ao banco;

```
func (c Call) Save(db *sql.DB) error {
    stmt, err := db.Prepare(`
        INSERT INTO calls values($1, $2, $3, $4)
    `)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // ...
}
```

porém quando passo o ponteiro como parametro um erro `panic` é exibido;

> http: panic serving [::1]:51111: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

a conexão é definida da seguinte maneira:

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

var db *sql.DB

func init() {
    db, _ := sql.Open("postgres", dsn)
    if err := db.Ping(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
}
```

A passagem do parametro ocorre assim:

```
err := c.Save(db)
// c é a struct que possui o método Save
```

Mesmo definindo no método que o parametro é um ponteiro esse erro de nil pointer acontece, porque?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o problema seja a variável criada localmente. Você está fazendo algo assim:

```
package main
import "fmt"

var variavel *int

func init() {
    variavel, _ := new(int), new(int)
    fmt.Println("init:", variavel)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("main:", variavel)
}
```

O print será:

```
init: 0x416020
main: <nil>
```

---

Para corrigir você deve usar `=` ao invés de `:=`. [Neste caso usar `variavel, _ = new(int), new(int)` resolveria.](https://play.golang.org/p/6NCI9TYsABG)

---

Troque o `db, _ := sql.Open("postgres", dsn)` para `db, _ = sql.Open("postgres", sn)`, assim você vai fazer com que o resultado fique na `var db *sql.DB` e não numa nova variável local do `init()`:

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

var db *sql.DB

func init() {
    db, _ = sql.Open("postgres", dsn) // Usando = ao invés de := 
    if err := db.Ping(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
}
```

Uma outra solução é criar uma outra variável, como:

```
func init() {
    dbX, _ := sql.Open("postgres", dsn) // Use :=
    if err := db.Ping(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
    db = dbX // Agora seta o db como valor do dbX, criado acima.
}
```

Comment: o linter não deveria informar que existem 2 variáveis com o mesmo nome?